# Azure SQL ports - expect on 1433 - but finding more

Tags: security, azure-sql-database, azure

Our security department has questioned why we have multiple ports open to our Azure SQL instance.

Ports highlighted as LISTENING are 443, 3006, 5002, 5432, 7443 and a few in the 16000 to 16018 area.

5432 seems to be Postgres and 5002 seems to by mySql, which we don't run. Investigation indicates that it's the SQL Gateway that actually has these ports open, but will not route them to our instance. Is that right?

Is there a way to bypass the gateway and have a direct connection, as we're struggling to alleviate concerns on these open ports. Except for Postgres and mySql, I'm not sure what the others are there for.

Answer (score 1):

> Our security department has questioned why we have multiple ports open to our Azure SQL instance.

You don't.

Those ports aren't open on SQL.  There's a regional gateway that either proxies or redirects the client connection to the actual SQL Server instance.  See

[Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse Analytics connectivity architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture?view=azuresql)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a configuration issue. For Azure SQL you should only need port 1433 open usually: [Azure SQL Database - IP Firewall Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#:%7E:text=To%20access%20Azure%20SQL%20Database,communication%20on%20TCP%20port%201433.)

If you are using ADO.NET version 4.5 or later then you may have to open a few additional ports in the range of 11000 to 11999 (again only if you're trying to connect to the database via ADO.NET 4.5 or greater): [ADO.NET 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/adonet-v12-develop-direct-route-ports)

If you're not using those other ports for anything else, you likely can secure them per your security department's recommendations.

Comment: From my research, it seems there is a Gateway in front of the SQL server, which Azure proxies connections through. See https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/stairway-to-microsoft-azure-sql-database-part-5-azure-sql-serve-server-firewall-and-virtual-network-setting). I think that proxy exposes all database type connections. It's that, which we're battling to get around - if at all possible. "Redirect" policy seems to be the answer, but not sure how.

Comment: @Craig Hmm I would agree. You might find a simplified walkthrough on what you need regarding changing from Proxy to Redirect connection policy here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdkqs7bZC_E